# Replace table if schema mistmatch in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, database-schema

I'm working on application which use SQLite3 a lot and want to make sure that tables are fine: they are what I expect from them (have correct columns, column types, notnull, etc.). My current apporach is to manually check data returned by `PRAGMA table_info()` and remove table if it's wrong.

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` check only table existence, but not does it match to passed description. It is useful in general, but not for type checks.

Is there a way to make such a check better way than I'm already doing it?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is to use the database `user_version` to track schema changes.  So the general procedure is:

On initial database creation, set the user version to 1, `PRAGMA USER_VERSION = 1`

In your program, check to see if tables need to be updated/deleted/recreated using something like the following pseudo-code (`current_schema_version` is initially 1 but gets incremented at every schema change).

```
if user_version == 0
    new database, so create all tables in the database
    set user_version = current_schema_version
else if user_version == current_schema_version - 1
    create/recreate tables, or whatever other adjustments have to be made for new schema
    set user_version = current_schema_version
endif
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It sounds like nice idea, but for cases when you want to version table/database schemas. In my case I only want to make sure that columns and its types do math, so it sadly will not work.

Comment: I'm not sure why it won't work in your case - can you explain?